# How Update my react-native appliction in app/play store without click

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, app-store, google-play-services

How can i update my installed application without clicking update button if there is a new update ?

I tried this library `react-native-version-check`

```js
import VersionCheck from 'react-native-version-check';

  // ...
  useEffect(() => {
    VersionCheck.needUpdate()
      .then(async res => {
        console.log(res.isNeeded);   
        if (res.isNeeded) {
          Linking.openURL(res.storeUrl);  
        }
      });
  })
  
  // ...
```

This is redirecting to store but i want auto update without clicking it from my app please help me.

Comment: are you useing `expo`?

Comment: No React-native CLI

Comment: Did I understood your need? Are you looking for a way to the user to update the app without having to doing it from the stores?

Comment: No i want update from store but it should be automatic .Without going to store by user